# Getting 104 error while accessing a web page

Tags: .net, asp.net-caching

One of user is  getting 104 (connection reset by peer) error while accessing one of the page in my application, though other pages are opening fine, problem persists only for this page and that too only on few users.

I tried clearing cookies on client machine's and enabling "Auto Detect Settings" but this did not work.

Any idea on how I can get this fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

i assume you mean [`10054 Connection reset by peer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> `WSAECONNRESET`
>
> `10054`
>
> **Connection reset by peer.**
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see [setsockopt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

Your application is crashing, or your router is closing the connection, or your firewall is closing the connection, or their router is closing the connection, or their firewall is closing the connection, or your application is closing the connection, or their ISP is closing the connection, or your ISP is closing the connection, or...